# Android Studio causing Thermal Shutdown

Tags: android-studio

Android studio is causing thermal shutdown on project build. 
I am using android studio 2.3.3 on core i7 with 8GB RAM

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue.
I had to update the drivers of intel dynamic platform thermal framework.
And now Android studio is running smooth.